# How to implement JSONP in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jsonp

Can anybody suggest, How can I implement Jquery **JSONP** in my **ASP.NET project**. I am already using **JQUERY AJAX**, sorry but I am just very new to JSONP implementation. My application flow is described below:

1) I am opening a **HTTP** page, where I have got JQuery **login** dialog box, from which **username** and **password** is posted to my **Login.aspx** page, which has got one method **"GetLoginDetails"** which takes posted **username** and **password** and sends to a **WEBSERVICE** which checks the users name and password and return back with **"success=true"**

2) so in my response I get "success=true", I read that value from jquery and works according to responded text on my client side it display message **"Logged in Successfully"**.

Please suggest how can I achieve above functionality using JQuery JSONP and .NET.